# Chain of Observables.map doesn't wait for answer from rest request

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, reactivex

```
return this.billingRest.getAccount()
        .map((response: any) => {
            this.logger.debug('initAccountAndPlans - after getAcccount');
            this.logger.debug("getAccount response", response);
            this.logger.debug('getAccount teamID=' + teamId +
                ' info=' + response.account.firstName + ' ' + response.account.lastName);
            this.account = response.account;
            return response;
        })
        .map( () => {
            return this.billingRest.getPlans()
                .map( (data) => {
                    this.logger.debug('getPlans result', data);
                    let plans = data;
                    if (this.utilService.isDefined(vm.usePilotPlan) && vm.usePilotPlan) {
                        plans = [];
                        plans.push(this.getPilotPlan());
                    }
                    logger.debug('getPlans=' +  JSON.stringify(data));
                    const screenPlans = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
                        const plan = plans[i];
                        const screenPlan = this.transformPlanToView(plan);
                        screenPlans.push(screenPlan);
                    };
                    if (screenPlans.length === 0) {
                        return Observable.throw({msg: 'cannot find plans'});
                    }
                    vm.planOptions = screenPlans;
                    this.logger.debug('currentTeam', this.sessionService.getCurrentTeam());
                    return this.billingRest.getCurrentPlan(teamId);
                }).map((response: any) => {
                    const currentPlan = response.plan;
                    this.logger.debug('currentPlan skuCode=' + currentPlan.sku);
                    vm.currentPlan = currentPlan;
                    const currentOrder = response.order;
                    vm.currentOrder = currentOrder;

                    vm.nextBillDate = this.getNextBillDate(currentOrder);
                    if (! this.utilService.isDefined(response.creditCard)) {
                        vm.currentPaymentMethod = {};
                    } else {
                        vm.currentPaymentMethod = response.creditCard;
                        this.logger.debug('currentPaymentMethod id=' + vm.currentPaymentMethod.uuid); // BraintreePaymentMethodId
                    }
                    this.logger.debug('currentPaymentMethod', vm.currentPaymentMethod);
                    vm.plan = this.getPlanById(this.planOptions, currentPlan); // for checkout
                    return Observable.throw({});
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("COŚ TU JEST NIE TAK" + error);
                    this.logger.exception('init-getPlans : Ajax Error')(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                }).subscribe();
        })
        .catch( (response) => {
            this.logger.exception('initAccountAndPlans : Ajax Error')(response);
            return observable.throw(response);
        });
}
```

This is my code. As you see i have one main chain and one substring of Observables.map operator. Everything works fine to the moment of

```
    return this.billingRest.getCurrentPlan(teamId);
            }).map((response: any) => {
                const currentPlan = response.plan;
```

It doesn't fire and the next map operator doesn't wait for response, and it throws error ' cannot read property of undefined ' . It behaves like it doesn't have subscribe, but actually it has. When i cast get CurrentPlan with toPromise(), the next map doesn't wait for result, but the function got fire. I don't know how to do, i don't understand behaviour of that function.

```
  getCurrentPlan (teamId) {
        console.log('GET CURRENTPLAN PRZED RESTEM')
        return this.http.get(this.restUrl + this.plansPrefix + '/' + teamId + '/getCurrentPlan', {observe: 'response'})
            .map( (response) => {
                console.log(" FULFILLED LOG ");
                return response.body;
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.log('GETCURRENTPLANNIEDZIALA');
                return Observable.throw(response);
            });
    };
```

Comment: `map` expects a *value* to be returned, not an observable, so it won't subscribe to a returned observable. Try `mergeMap` (or `switchMap` depending upon the behaviour you require).

Comment: I tryed this, it doesn't help aswell. It still doesn't fire.

Comment: If your map function calls another service (e.g. returns another observable or promise), then use `mergeMap`.  If it just processes the result but does not call another service, use `map`.

Comment: Yes i understand this. But my service also return a value as you can see it is respone.body. So it still doesn't help .

Comment: no, your service doesn't return a value. it returns `Observable<Object>` and you should try what colleague suggested.

Comment: I tryed this and it doesn't help. But in my way of thinking in case of map service returns response.body( value ) . But catch throws observable ? Is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

In this block

```
  return this.billingRest.getCurrentPlan(teamId);
}).map((response: any) => {
  const currentPlan = response.plan;
```

I don't see where **teamId** comes from. Perhaps you mean `this.teamId`?

So perhaps , 'cannot read property of undefined' may be coming from `response.plan` because response is undefined?

As a bonus, I think this

```
const screenPlans = [];
for (let i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
  const plan = plans[i];
  const screenPlan = this.transformPlanToView(plan);
  screenPlans.push(screenPlan);
};
```

can be written as this

```
const screenPlans = plans.map(plan => this.transformPlanToView(plan))
```

Answer (score 0):

initAccountAndPlans(vm) {

```
    this.planOptions = [];
    this.plan = {}; // selected plan from planOptions
    this.currentPlan = {}; // currentPlan
    const teamId = this.sessionService.getCurrentTeam().uuid;

    /*          return billingRest.getPlans()
              .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
              })
              .catch(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
     */
    return this.billingRest.getAccount()
        .map((response: any) => {
            this.logger.debug('initAccountAndPlans - after getAcccount');
            this.logger.debug("getAccount response", response);
            this.logger.debug('getAccount teamID=' + teamId +
                ' info=' + response.account.firstName + ' ' + response.account.lastName);
            this.account = response.account;
            return response;
        })
        .map( () => {
            return this.billingRest.getPlans()
                .map( (data) => {
                    this.logger.debug('getPlans result', data);
                    let plans = data;
                    if (this.utilService.isDefined(vm.usePilotPlan) && vm.usePilotPlan) {
                        plans = [];
                        plans.push(this.getPilotPlan());
                    }
                    logger.debug('getPlans=' +  JSON.stringify(data));
                    const screenPlans = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
                        const plan = plans[i];
                        const screenPlan = this.transformPlanToView(plan);
                        screenPlans.push(screenPlan);
                    };
                    if (screenPlans.length === 0) {
                        return Observable.throw({msg: 'cannot find plans'});
                    }
                    vm.planOptions = screenPlans;
                    this.logger.debug('currentTeam', this.sessionService.getCurrentTeam());
                    return this.billingRest.getCurrentPlan(teamId);
                })
                .switchMap((response: any) => {
                    const currentPlan = response.plan;
                    this.logger.debug('currentPlan skuCode=' + currentPlan.sku);
                    vm.currentPlan = currentPlan;
                    const currentOrder = response.order;
                    vm.currentOrder = currentOrder;

                    vm.nextBillDate = this.getNextBillDate(currentOrder);
                    if (! this.utilService.isDefined(response.creditCard)) {
                        vm.currentPaymentMethod = {};
                    } else {
                        vm.currentPaymentMethod = response.creditCard;
                        this.logger.debug('currentPaymentMethod id=' + vm.currentPaymentMethod.uuid); // BraintreePaymentMethodId
                    }
                    this.logger.debug('currentPaymentMethod', vm.currentPaymentMethod);
                    vm.plan = this.getPlanById(this.planOptions, currentPlan); // for checkout
                    return Observable.throw({});
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("COŚ TU JEST NIE TAK" + error);
                    this.logger.exception('init-getPlans : Ajax Error')(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                }).subscribe();
        })
        .catch( (response) => {
            this.logger.exception('initAccountAndPlans : Ajax Error')(response);
            return observable.throw(response);
        });
}
```

That is a complete function, teamId is prepared by sessionService.getCurrentTeam().uuid. Switch map and merge map doesn't work. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: I still didn't resolve the problem :( So if anyone have idea, i will really enjoy it.